# Adding days in Java timezone Eastern European Summer Time (EEST)

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I've written a Java app in which I start the date at Jan 1 00:00 of a particular year. Then I increment the day 355 times and print out the results along the way. I was trying to understand how the timezones work around daylight savings time, and if adding 1 day would shift the time from midnight to 1am when crossing into daylight savings. My code looks like:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
cal.set(2008, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
for ( int i = 0; i < 355; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

When running in my default time zone (US Eastern), the output looks like as I would expect:

```
01/01/2008 00:00:00 EST
01/02/2008 00:00:00 EST
01/03/2008 00:00:00 EST
01/04/2008 00:00:00 EST
...
```

and when I cross into daylight savings time, I get

```
03/10/2008 00:00:00 EDT
03/11/2008 00:00:00 EDT
03/12/2008 00:00:00 EDT
```

When I use a timezone that observes Eastern European summer time, (in this case, I chose the Africa/Cairo timezone) I get the output:

```
01/01/2008 00:00:00 EET
01/02/2008 00:00:00 EET
01/03/2008 00:00:00 EET
01/04/2008 00:00:00 EET
01/05/2008 00:00:00 EET
```

but when I cross into Eastern European summer time, I get:

```
04/25/2008 01:00:00 EEST
04/26/2008 01:00:00 EEST
04/27/2008 01:00:00 EEST
```

And strangely when EEST ends, I still get

```
08/29/2008 01:00:00 EET
08/30/2008 01:00:00 EET
```

I'm confused as to why these timezones behave differently and if it is a bug with Africa/Cairo timezone, or if I am misunderstanding how the timezones work...

Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: which java version you are using? Have you updated your JRE timezone DB with latest one?

Comment: I'm using java 6 update 29...updating to 30 now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cairo time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=53&syear=2000) changes into daylight saving time *at midnight* - so the hour between midnight on April 25th 2008 was skipped... the wall clocks went:

```
04/24/2008 23:59:58
04/24/2008 23:59:59
04/25/2008 01:00:00
04/25/2008 01:00:01
```

Try adding one day at a time from 2am in the US Eastern time zone and you'll see the same thing - it'll go to 03:00 at some point.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve exactly - I tend to think it's better to either add "a number of experienced milliseconds" to a date/time in a particular time zone, or add "a number of *logical* milliseconds" to a local date/time, which doesn't take time zones into account. When you convert from local time to time in a specific zone, you need to consider the possibility of ambiguity (one local time occurring twice) or skipping (one local time not occurring at all).

For added fun, last year Samoa skipped December 30th entirely, due to changing its time zone from -14 to +10...

EDIT: Oh, and my standard recommendation applies: ditch java.util.Calendar/Date, and go with [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)

Comment: Jon, thanks. I believe that is part of the problem. But I would expect to see similar behavior when leaving EEST...the inconsistency seems incorrect. But to clarify what it is I'm trying to do, I'm basically just trying to create a set of time periods that go from midnight-midnight every day. I understand on the days when we cross over savings time that the time period may be 23 or 25 hours (or that midnight may not even exist on that day)

Comment: @JeffStorey: No, because when *leaving* EEST, the local time 01:00 is experienced *twice*. Basically once you've left midnight, you no longer ever get to a situation where the local time doesn't occur.

Comment: So it looks like adding "1 day" has a different effect in DST vs EEST since EEST occurs at midnight but DST occurs at 2am - is that correct?

Comment: a response to your edit on JODA time. I normally would, but I'm integrating with an existing API that uses java Calendar/Date. I know I can convert between the two, so I'll do that if need be.

Comment: @JeffStorey: I'm not sure what you mean by "DST" here, but adding "one day" attempts to get to "the same (local) time on the next date"... but when that local time *doesn't exist* then there's a problem. It's not that adding a day has a different meaning - it's that you happen to be avoiding the problematic time in your US sample. As I say, try starting at 2am in the US and you'll see the same thing...

Comment: I understand now. That makes sense. I just tried that and the same behavior exists (it goes from 0200 to 0100). So I'm basically trying to print out equal intervals that always start at 0000. When that time doesn't exist, it was 0100, but then I want it to start again at 0000 the next day -- not sure how to accomplish that in a general way.

Comment: @JeffStorey: Ideally, deal in `LocalDate` Joda time values to start with :) But if not, just set the hour of day to 0 on each iteration...